# Bootstrap and CSS linear gradient not covering the entire page

Tags: css

Im using bootstrap and my own css formatting to make my website. Unfortunately the linear gradient I have applied to my background image is stopping at the bottom of my middle content

[Here's the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mObIb.jpg)

```
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url(Imagery/GrandmaCover.jpg);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

And there's the code for my body

Comment: what if you add `height:100vh` to your body ?

Comment: Omds thank you so much, it worked!